# Breakpoints set directly in typescript reducer function is not hi t, when set in main-client.js it is

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, react-redux, visual-studio-2017

I'm wondering if anyone else has had this issue, it only seems to happen to new typescript files I add to the project.

The breakpoints don't hit but window.alert is called so things are definitely happening.

If I open main-client.js and find the javascript version of the function and I attempt to place a breakpoint on that line visual studio switches me to the typescript file, places the breakpoint correctly which then hits on execution!

Another interesting thing is I can step into the typescript from within react javascript.

I have no idea where to start to look to try and fix this issue, the project in question is more or less a standard React+redux visual studio asp.net core web project.

Perhaps relevant - Visual Assist X does not 'see' the files when I do alt+shift+o even though they're in the solution explorer but it's doing that with all files so it might just be broken in VS2017.

Comment: Is the code executed while the page is initially loaded? This is normal then. VS cannot debug JS inside a page in an external browser until the loading of the page was finished.

Comment: No this is after the page has loaded, specifically it's a reducer function which is being called but the breakpoint not being hit. Any new file I add seems to ahve this problem but the existing ones are fine. Really weird!